# Java Instance of Class Life Time

Tags: java

If I created an Instance of a class how long does the Object live for and what does its life cycle depend on?

For example I have classA which I instantiate in my main class like so:

```
classA ca = new classA();
```

Does this object last as long as the runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, It depends on how long the object have a reference associated to itself(read about type of ref for detail). for ex.

```
classA ca = new classA();
classA ca = new classB();  //first reference assigned to some other object
```

Now your first object is eligible for garbage collection and will be destroyed in the nextGC cycle.

Comment: I read about GC so I know the life cycle of the objects now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there exist the live reference to it, After it it may still exist in the heap (without any reference) but it is ready to be garbage collected, so when GC runs the very next time , it will find this instance and GC it so its dead

**For example**

```
{
  classA ca = new classA();
}
```

Instance of classA gets created in the block and there is the reference to it `ca` which is certainly live as far as the control is in that block, after that it is ready to be collected by GC

Comment: ... and possibly a bit longer. There's an important distinction between "eligible for GC" and "garbage-collected".

Answer (score 0):

In Java the instance/Object lives until it has some reachable reference.

```
classA ca = classA();
```

As the newly created object has only one reference pointing this instance variable to null makes this object eligible for garbage collection

```
ca = null;
```